# Arcgis FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND not select exactly coodinate?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, coordinates, features, area

I'm working with ArcGis API. I push my Feature Layer on map in `MODE_ONDEMAND`. But when I select feature `(selectTask)`, the coordinates come out as [692010, 101011], with no decimal places. What I want is more accuracy, for instance: [692010.21212 , 101011.21212]. Meanwhile, in `MODE_SNAPSHOT`, everything is ok. Why is this?

UPDATE: Here is results `MODE_ONDEMAND`: 
[image: ONDEMAND MODE]

And Here is results `MODE_SNAPSHOT` : 
[image: SNAPSHOT]

Here is my code when add Feature Layer:

```
    var layer = vGis.Params.layers.addFeatureLayer(featureserver.url,
                { mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
                    //mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
                    outFields: ["*"],
                    id: featureserver.id,
                    opacity: 1,
                }, filter);
```

Comment: Those values are more ***precise***, but are not likely to be more *accurate*.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you give me a solution?  @@

Comment: I still don't see a problem.

Comment: Problem: How to use `MODE_ONDEMAND` get exactly coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Set quantize to false before adding featureLayer to map.

```
featureLayer.quantize = false;
```

Comment: Thanks you, but it's not working !

Comment: Is this an ArcGIS portal feature layer?

Comment: It' s featureLayer from Mapsever. Link like: http://192.168.1.29:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Folder/Map_City/MapServer/4 . I get it and push on my map.